# Why can I vary the position of the noun phrase only in certain sentences?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, prepositional-phrases, complements, adjuncts

It is possible to say this:

> 1. It formed *inside him* an ambition to teach his students all the more.

I brought the "inside him" to the front of the noun phrase "an ambition to..." since the noun phrase was too long as below.

> 2. It formed an ambition to teach his students all the more *inside him*.

But I realized that it does not always work.

> 3. He kept in the book bag an apple. (Does not work --- so literary)
> 4. I have to say: He kept an apple in the book bag.

3rd one sounded so literary that I would not consider using it if I were writing just a formal email or an essay. So, why is it possible to reverse the order and still make it sound normal only in 1st sentence?

Is it usable only with noun and noun phrases, or is it also possible with adjectives?

Please give me some examples of reversed sentences that includes preposition that includes both time and place.

Comment: _He kept in the book bag a wooden apple that he had had ever since his visit to the forestry visitors centre five years previously_ works (even without an apostrophe).  Far better than placing 'in the book bag' at the end of the sentence. This shows that there are no inviolable syntactic restraints; what sounds right, what links adverbials more closely to what they're modifying, what is clearer and less clunky are the deciding factors. (And I'd say sentence (2) here is at best very clumsy.)

Comment: I'm not sure that any of your sentences mean what you intend them to mean. In the first one, what does the initial  'It' refer to?  Does it refer to an entity in a previous sentence that you have not given us? If not then your sentence is incorrect. At best you need to add some punctuation.

Comment: It refers to an entity in a previous sentence. To make long story short, this "it" is a situation he went through.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Is there a name for this usage? I would really like to look at some of the examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Probably no inviolable constraints, but constraints still, as you say; "clunky" and "what sounds better" can probably be specified, even though the factors may be to some degree semantic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it's about heavy noun phrase shift. Or at least that's what I put in my answer ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. It formed **inside him** an ambition to teach his students all the more.
> 2. It formed an ambition to teach his students all the more **inside him**.
> 3. He kept **in the book bag** an apple. (awkward or marked)
> 4. He kept an apple **in the book bag**.

The differing acceptability of these examples is due to a phenomenon known as *HEAVY NOUN PHRASE SHIFT*. It gives us the illusion that we are able to move the preposition phrases in the sentence around, but really what we are moving is not the preposition phrases; it's the noun phrase *ambition to teach his students all the more* on the one hand and *an apple* on the other.

We term a noun phrase as *heavy* when it is long. You'll notice that the noun phrase *ambition to teach his students all the more* is very heavy. The noun phrase *an apple* is, of course, rather light. When a noun phrase is the Direct Object in a sentence, it normally occurs directly after the verb (or if there is an Indirect Object, after the Indirect Object). If there are other phrases, for example locative or temporal Adjuncts or Complements, we cannot just switch their positions willy-nilly, or the sentence will be deemed ungrammatical:

- *I met in the office canteen just now Bob.

In the sentence above I put the Direct Object *Bob* after the Adjuncts (or "adverbials") *in the office canteen* and *just now*. Because *Bob* doesn't directly follow the verb, the sentence would be regarded as ungrammatical. However! If we make the  Direct Object very *heavy*, in other words if we make it *long* we can move the Direct Object to the end of the sentence, no problem:

- I met in the office canteen just now that guy Bob who you bumped into the other day.

Now that the Direct Object is a ten word noun phrase, *that guy Bob who you bumped into the other day*, we can move it right over all the other phrases to the end of the sentence. It is perfectly grammatical.

In the Original Poster's examples (1) is fine because the noun phrase *an ambition to teach his students all the more* is heavy enough to move to the end of the sentence past the preposition phrase *inside him*. But in the Original Poster's third example, *an apple* is too short to justify moving to the end of the sentence. It needs to come after the verb and before the preposition phrase *in the book bag* to sound natural. But this has nothing to do with the preposition phrase, it's just because the noun phrase, the Direct Object, is very light. The feeling that we're moving the preposition phrase is a kind of illusion.

Comment: It is possible with preposition phrase involving time, right? Is "I met..." sentence using both time preposition phrase and place preposition phrase?

Comment: @sooeithdk Yes, that's right there's a temporal (time) phrase and a locative one ( a place one) too. The noun phrase can move past many different types of other phrase. :)

Comment: Those are just now and in the office canteen, right? Thank you for your answer! It provided clarity to me.

Comment: @sooeithdk Yes, that's right. My pleasure, glad it was helpful!

Comment: Hmm ... In re #1: **a)** Seems to me that *inside him* is an object PC and belongs after *ambition &c* **b** What really needs explaining is why the *best* way of phrasing this sentence, to my ear at least, is *...formed an ambition inside him to teach his students all the more&c*. I suspect it's because putting *inside him* at the end makes that appear to be a modifier on the infinitival.

Comment: @StoneyB Interesting. But I'm not sure there. If you moved it to after *ambition*,  it seems to me that that  would just be a case of extraposition from noun phrase movement (where you move the heavy right modifying stuff out of the noun phrase to the end of the sentence).

Comment: @Stoney B That's what I was trying to include in my question, but I was afraid that it would get too long, so let me just ask you here. That was one of my other option I was trying to use, but when I did some thinking, I was not totally sure if it would be ok even though it sounded fine to me. The problem was this: He gained ability yesterday to fly. I strongly believe that "yesterday" is temporal phrase and breaking down noun phrase "ability to fly" as you have done with " ...an ambition inside him to teach...." should create no problem at all, but it just sounded off to me.

Comment: @StoneyB But, of course, if it was right after *ambition* then it could equally well be a PP post-modifying the noun. So there could be noun-modifiers or clause ones. But the only way, I reckon, to have *inside him* before the DO is if the DO moves. The PP could be  a Locative Complement or an Adjunct in the clause structure, but it would still normally have to come after the DO. For example, the OP's book-bag example has *in the bag* as a Locative Complement, but it still needs to after the DO unless the DO's long.

Comment: Well, 'cepn it don't work any better with light 'modifying stuff': *It formed an ambition to teach inside him* not so good as *It formed an ambition inside him to teach*. Is it relevant that I'd call both *inside him* and *to teach* stuff 'modifying' amibition, the one dependent on *formed* and the other on *ambition*?

Comment: So why is it not possible to say "I gained an ability yesterday to fly" , but " it formed an ability inside him to teach his students all the more"?

Comment: @sooeithdk *Inter alia*, because *yesterday* cannot be taken to modify *ability*, wheras *inside him* **is** the location of the ability. After *ability* is the **only** place in the sentence where you can't put *yesterday*.

Comment: @sooeithdk That last example you gave is an instance of *extraposition from noun phrase movement*. This is when we take some phrases that are post-modifying the noun and move *those* to the end of the sentence. So for example we can have *I met that man today from the tax office*. In that sentence the PP *from the tax office* has been moved out of the noun phrase *that man from the tax office* and put at the end of the sentence. That's what's happening in your "ability to fly" example. The infinitival modifier has broken off and moved to the end. ...

Comment: Oh.. I see now. So if I say " he gained an ability from the wizard to fly freely", would it be acceptable? By the way, please forgive my example sentence...it was hard coming up with one.

Comment: @StoneyB, sooeithdk, The longer the post-modifier the better the result will be. So "He gained the skill yesterday of being able to fly round the room whilst balancing plates on his elbows" will be fine (erm in terms of *yesterday*). In your example, the *to fly* is too short to justify being moved ...

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me so greatly....by the way, is it one of those discontinuous noun phrase?

Comment: Also, according to Stoney.B, yesterday is not usable because it does not modify ability... is it the reason I cannot use that "ability to fly" sentence, or is it because "to fly" is too short?

Comment: @sooeithdk I'd add that usually when you get twisted up in these things it's not a matter of what's grammatical or parsible or acceptable but of Great Mother English giving you a little poke and saying "Do you *really* want to do that? Wouldn't you be happier with, oh, an *it-* cleft? Or maybe put that obnoxious *yesterday* at the *front* of the sentence?"

Comment: Well....I was just trying to understand things better as I did not have any clue at all....that's what people say, though, "why don't you keep it simple"

Comment: @StoneyB That StoneyB fellow. You just made me come back and sign in again now I've read some of your comments I missed before! In your "ambition inside him to teach" I reckon you're right, they're both modifying *ambition* and that particular versions best because it keeps the most important info till last. But you can't move a PP postmodifier to before the noun, it seems to me. For that reason I'm pretty sure that in OP's example *inside him* is an Adjunct in the clause structure not a noun modifier. But I'm tired and out of practice with grammar discussions. We should do this more. G'night!

Comment: @sooeithdk Yeah ... the thing is, in the Real World (as opposed to isolated sentences in textbooks), some things in the sentence are more important than others, and what you focus on is getting the important things where they'll be noticed -- then everything else tends to fall into place.

Comment: ... 'awkward or marked': nice. but 'or marked for lyrical effect' (as OP points out) / 'or marked for emphasis' ... specifies 'for what'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, exactly. I suspect that when things are marked it means they can be justified by certain information packaging considerations, but will otherwise sound odd if these conditions don't apply. (So "Happy he is" will normally be awkward, but if we've mentioned him being happy in the previous sentence it'll be ok: "I said he was happy, and happy he is!") But info packaging is really complex - and hurts my tiny brain cells if I think about it too much ...

Comment: 'We tells him to go, and he goes away' definitely lacks a certain something. I wonder if a 'What varieties of marking are there?' question would be too broad? // I've been able to check for previous instances of 'heavy noun phrase shift' on ELU; you're well represented answerwise. But it would be cheating to reverse my vote here, as I couldn't find previous related strings until you posted the term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think this question was a bit different originally, as it was originally about why we seemed to be able to move the PPs about, not the NPs. So the original point of my post is not to show why we can move the NPs about but why it looked as if the PPs were moving! Thanks for not reversing your vote, though (but you can, of course, if you want to) // I think the 'marked' question would get a colossal answer!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off saying "It formed in him . . ." rather than "It formed inside him . . ."

"He kept in the book bag an apple" sounds as though you just got off the boat from Germany. (Or maybe off the train from somewhere in rural Pennsylvania. You know, as in "Throw Mama from the train a kiss.") You have two choices with that sentence. If you're focusing on what he kept in the book bag, say "In the book bag, he kept an apple." If you're focusing on where he kept apple, say "He kept an apple in the book bag."